# Overflow hiding my image

Tags: html, css

I try to make image gallery with openable image, but the problem is when a image is opened and monitor or browser window height is small, the top side of image is hidden. Any option with overflow property does not work for me. My current code to example is below. Any suggestions how to fix or what I do wrong ?

```js
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "flex";
  document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";
  document.body.style.overflow = "visible";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "flex";
 var modal = document.getElementById("modalContent");
   var divImg = slides[slideIndex-1];
 var img = divImg.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
 var imgWidth = img.width;
 var imgHeight = img.height;
 modal.style.width = imgWidth + "px";
 modal.style.height = imgHeight + "px";
 
  document.onkeydown = function(x) {
  if (document.getElementById('myModal').style.display == "flex") {
  x = x || window.event;
  if (x.keyCode == '37') {
   plusSlides(-1)
  } else if (x.keyCode == '39') {
   plusSlides(1)
  }
 }
  }
}
```

```css
/* Center gallery */
.row {
 margin: 0 auto 30px;
 text-align: center;
}

/* Padding in gallery */
.row > .column {
  padding: 16px 8px;
}

.column {
  width: 320px;
  height: 320px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 4;
 
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 
 overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto ;
  padding: 0;
 align-self: center;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* Close hover */
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Slide iamge */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* Pointer cursor */
.cursor {
  cursor: pointer
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* Removing white line on bottom of image in gallery */
.mySlides img {
  width: auto !important;
 max-height: 720px;
 max-width: 720px;
}

/* Shadow and opacity animation */
img.hover-shadow {
  transition: 0.4s;
}
/* Shadow and opacity of gallery image */
.hover-shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="column">
  <img src="https://www.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/10-dithering-opt.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
 </div>
 <div class="column">
  <img src="https://amazingslider.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/dandelion.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
 </div>
 <div class="column">
  <img src="http://www.qygjxz.com/data/out/114/5838619-image.png" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
 </div>
 <div class="column">
  <img src="https://camo.mybb.com/e01de90be6012adc1b1701dba899491a9348ae79/687474703a2f2f7777772e6a71756572797363726970742e6e65742f696d616765732f53696d706c6573742d526573706f6e736976652d6a51756572792d496d6167652d4c69676874626f782d506c7567696e2d73696d706c652d6c69676874626f782e6a7067" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(4)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
 </div>
 <div class="column">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(5)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
 </div>
 <div class="column">
  <img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/jQuery-Plugin-For-Fullscreen-Image-Viewer-Chroma-Gallery.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(6)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
 </div>
 <div class="column">
  <img src="https://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/5718897981_10faa45ac3_b-640x624.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(7)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
 </div>
 <div class="column">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_avatar3.png" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(8)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
 </div>
</div>

<!--Modal image slide show-->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
 <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
 <div class="modal-content" id="modalContent">

  <div class="mySlides">
   <div class="numbertext">1 / 8</div>
   <img src="https://www.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/10-dithering-opt.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides">
   <div class="numbertext">2 / 8</div>
   <img src="https://amazingslider.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/dandelion.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides">
   <div class="numbertext">3 / 8</div>
   <img src="http://www.qygjxz.com/data/out/114/5838619-image.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides">
   <div class="numbertext">4 / 8</div>
   <img src="https://camo.mybb.com/e01de90be6012adc1b1701dba899491a9348ae79/687474703a2f2f7777772e6a71756572797363726970742e6e65742f696d616765732f53696d706c6573742d526573706f6e736976652d6a51756572792d496d6167652d4c69676874626f782d506c7567696e2d73696d706c652d6c69676874626f782e6a7067" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides">
   <div class="numbertext">5 / 8</div>
   <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides">
   <div class="numbertext">6 / 8</div>
   <img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/jQuery-Plugin-For-Fullscreen-Image-Viewer-Chroma-Gallery.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides">
   <div class="numbertext">7 / 8</div>
   <img src="https://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/5718897981_10faa45ac3_b-640x624.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides">
   <div class="numbertext">8 / 8</div>
   <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_avatar3.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>
   <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
   <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you not want the scrollbars to appear when the image modal is open?

Comment: When you open image in small height, the top side of image is hidden and I want to see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One line fix: remove `width: auto!important` from the `.mySlides img` css.

Then the image will scale to the screen width when the modal is open.

EDIT: Change `display: flex` to `display: block` on your modal. This solves your height problem on smaller height screens. But now your content is not vertically centered. You are trying to use flexbox in the midst of other things, and it is not meant for that. This is why you are getting strange behavior.

To mitigate this problem, use a media query or javascript to explicitly set the `display: flex` to `display: block` on smaller screen heights, because vertically aligning doesn't make sense there anyways since the image will always be greater than the screen height.

This gives you the best of both worlds:

1. On large screens, the image modal is vertically centered
2. On smaller screens, the image *will not* be cut off on the top like before, and vertically centering doesn't matter. You can add a small `margin-top` or something to add some space between top of screen and image.

Comment: When I do it the top side of image will be still hidden on small height, and image will look like a sneeze

Comment: Adjust your max-height/max-width and parent element styles to fix this. But the problem of overflowing width on smaller screens is resolved by the removal of `width: auto!important`. If there was a fiddle I could make this for you, I am not familiar with the SO code snippets.

Comment: I do not have problem with overflowing width. I have problem when I open image on monitor or browser window that HEIGHT is less thane image height, then the top side of image will be hidden and I want to see it.

Comment: Awesome, happy to help! By the way, looks like you are setting the `flex` in your `openModal` function. Just an FYI in case you go around looking for CSS that you will never find because it's added at runtime, haha.

Comment: Yes, I change it in javascript :)

Answer (score 0):

Well from the snippet i would say that the `Overflow: hidden;` property in `.column` might cause some trouble try deleting it or set it to `Overflow: scroll;`

Edit: The `Overflow: ;` has to be either `Overflow-x: ;` or `Overflow-y: ;` depending on the axis.

Edit: `document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";` in your openmodal function Might also need the right axis (I'm bad at functions but it's worth a shot ^^)

Comment: Your second edit: where is there a function in that line? :P

Comment: @Lansana 


   `function openModal() {
      document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "flex";
      document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
     }` That function ^^

Comment: I see, I thought you were referring to the specific line of code itself, since it's 
a statement.

Comment: Nah it's just the line inside the function ^^

Comment: An `overflow` style can be used without specifying the axis.

Comment: @JacquesMarais Please explain how, i would like to know how that could ever work ^^

Comment: For example `overflow: auto;` or `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: I do not want see full column, I what to see full image when it is opened, but when I opened on small height, the top side of image is hidden.

Comment: @Marek You could add in `Height: XXvh;` `Width: XXvw;` to let it scale with the viewport (Browser window). XX = 1-100.

Comment: @D3nj1 This will reduce the image when the broswer windows will be smaller, but I maybe use it

Comment: @Marek exactly ^^